# Logical generators of groups and $\mathrm{Aut}$-bases

Tags: gr.group-theory, lo.logic, model-theory

An element $s$ of a group $G$ is a *logical generator* of $G$ iff every element of $G$ can be defined in the first order language of groups with $s$ as a parameter. In this case we may call $G$  a *logically cyclic* group. This is equivalent to say that for any elementary extension $G^{\ast}$ of $G$ and any automorphism $\alpha:G^{\ast}\to G^{\ast}$, the condition $\alpha(s)=s$ implies $\alpha_{|_G}=\mathrm{id}$.

As a result, the set $\{ s\}$ is an $\mathrm{Aut}$-basis of $G$ in terms of [1] (i.e., every automorphism of $G$ is uniquely determined by its value on $s$).

I started to study logically cyclic groups in [2]. Recently, I realized that in fact I don't have any example of a group which is not logically cyclic but it has a singleton $\mathrm{Aut}$-basis.  So, here is my question:

**Is it true that if $\{ s\}$ is an $\mathrm{Aut}$-basis of $G$, then $s$ is a logical generator of $G$?**

[1] G. Cutolo, C. Nicotera: Subgroups defining automorphisms in locally nilpotent groups, Forum Mathematicum, **15** (2003).

[2] M. Shahryari: On logically cyclic groups, J. Group Theory, **18** (2015).

Comment: An observation: if $\{s\}$ is an Aut-basis onf $G$, then $G$ is abelian. Indeed, the inner automorphism $g\mapsto g^s$ fixes $s$, hence it is the identity, i.e., $s\in Z(G)$; but then *all* inner automorphisms fix $s$, hence they are the identity, i.e., $G$ is abelian.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$\{1\}$ is an Aut-basis of the group of profinite integers $\hat{\mathbb Z}$, but since this group has cardinality $2^\omega$, it has no logical generator. However, every element of $\hat{\mathbb Z}$ is *type-definable* from $1$ (i.e., any pair of distict elements are distinguishable by a first-order formula with parameter $1$); using Ali Enayat’s terminology, the structure $\langle\hat{\mathbb Z},+,1\rangle$ is *Leibnizian*. (Conversely, if $G$ is the group reduct of a $\mathbb Z$-group such that $\{1\}$ is an Aut-basis of $G$, then all elements of $G$ are type-definable from $1$, and $G$ embeds in $\hat{\mathbb Z}$; see my paper [Rigid models of Presburger arithmetic](https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.05797).)

Similarly, if $p$ is any prime, the group of $p$-adic integers $\mathbb Z_p$ has no logical generator (being uncountable), but all its elements are type-definable from $1$, thus $\{1\}$ is an Aut-basis.

Note that “every element of $G$ is type-definable from $s$” gives you a general property to consider that is intermediate between “$\{s\}$ is an Aut-basis of $G$”, and “$s$ is a logical generator of $G$”.

Comment: The best natural example. Thank you so much. The intermediate property is also very nice generalization.